# How to determine the spectral measurement of a matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ a linear operator whose matrix in the canonical base is

$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ 2 & -3 \end{pmatrix}.$

Find the expression of the spectral measure $\mu_{v}$ of $T$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: only a diaginalization of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

The resolvent of $T$ is
$$
      (\lambda I-T)^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda-1 & -2 \\ -2 & \lambda+3\end{array}\right)^{-1} \\
   = \frac{1}{(\lambda-1)(\lambda+3)-4}\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda+3 & 2 \\ 2 & \lambda-1\end{array}\right) \\
   = \frac{1}{(\lambda+1+2\sqrt{2})(\lambda+1-2\sqrt{2})}\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda+3 & 2 \\ 2 & \lambda-1\end{array}\right)
$$
This has a partial fraction decomposition equal to
$$
           \frac{1}{\lambda+1+2\sqrt{2}}A+\frac{1}{\lambda+1-2\sqrt{2}}B
$$
where
$$
            A=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow -1-2\sqrt{2}}(\lambda+1+2\sqrt{2})(\lambda I-T)^{-1}=\frac{1}{-4\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}2-2\sqrt{2} & 2 \\ 2 & -2-2\sqrt{2}\end{array}\right) \\
    B=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow -1+2\sqrt{2}}(\lambda+1-2\sqrt{2})(\lambda I-T)^{-1}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}2+2\sqrt{2} & 2 \\ 2 & -2 + 2 \sqrt{2}\end{array}\right)
$$
You can check that $A$, $B$ are orthogonal projections, with $A+B=I$ and $AB=BA=0$. The spectral measure $\mu$ is
$$
     \mu(S) = \chi_{\{-1-2\sqrt{2}\}}(S)A + \chi_{\{-1+2\sqrt{2}\}}(S)B
$$